# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una función de validación retorne verdadero o falso sin terminar el proceso?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Esta es mi primera pregunta, debo hacer una función que reciba como parámetro un array y lo ordene preguntando de manera creciente o decreciente, pero que debe tener una función que valide dicho array retornando verdadero si es valido y falso si es invalido para el proceso, no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo. Dejo el código por acá, espero que puedan ayudarme.

```
function ordenar(array){
   function validar (array){
       if(!Array.isArray(array) || array.length == 0){
           return false;
           }
           else{
               for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
               if( typeof array[i] !=='number'){
               return false;
               }
           }
       }
           return true;
   }

   var cicloOpciones = true;
   while(cicloOpciones){
       var opciones = prompt("Escriba el numero para una opcion: \n 1 - creciente. \n 2 - decreciente");
       
       if(opciones == 1 || opciones == 2){
           cicloOpciones = false
       }
       else{
           alert("opcion no disponible")
       }
   }

   if(opciones == 1){
       var aux
       for(var d = 0; d < array.length; d++){
           for(var e = 0; e < array.length - d; e++){
               if(array[e] > array[e+1]){
                   aux = array[e];
                   array[e] = array[e+1];
                   array[e+1] = aux;
               }
           }
       }
       console.log(array);
   }

   if(opciones == 2){
       var aux
       for(var d = 0; d < array.length; d++){
           for(var e = 0; e < array.length - d; e++){
               if(array[e] < array[e+1]){
                   aux = array[e];
                   array[e] = array[e+1];
                   array[e+1] = aux;
               }
           }
       }
       console.log(array);
   }
   
}
```

Comment: *pero debe tener una función que valide dicho array* -> No entiendo, más que nada lo de validar dicho array... ¿Qué debe validar para que retorne true o false?

Comment: validar que el parametro que se le de, sea un array, y que su contenido sean solo numeros, si cumple con eso, retornar true y seguir con el resto de la funcion de ordenamiento, y si retorna false que no

Answer (score 1):

Vemos que tu función donde validas el array funciona correctamente:

```js
function validar(array) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length === 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (typeof array[i] !== 'number') {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(validar([1, 2, 3])); // array de números => true
console.log(validar(['1', 2, 3])); // array de strings y números => false
console.log(validar([])); // array sin elementos => false
console.log(validar('1')); // es un string y no un array => false
console.log(validar(1)); // es un number y no un array => false
console.log(validar()); // no recibe ningún parámetro => false
```

Ahora, lo recomendable sería que la función **`validar(array)`** lo tengas fuera de tu función **`ordenar(array)`** para que primero valides si el array que recibe tu función es correcto o no, en donde si dicha validación retorna **`true`**, te enviará a la función donde ordena el array, de lo contrario, solo retorna **`false`** y no ocurre nada:

```js
function validar(array) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (typeof array[i] !== 'number') {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return ordenar(array);
}

function ordenar(array) {
  var cicloOpciones = true;
  while (cicloOpciones) {
    var opciones = prompt('Escriba el numero para una opcion: \n 1 - creciente. \n 2 - decreciente');

    if (opciones == 1 || opciones == 2) {
      cicloOpciones = false;
    } else {
      alert('opcion no disponible');
    }
  }

  if (opciones == 1) {
    var aux;
    for (var d = 0; d < array.length; d++) {
      for (var e = 0; e < array.length - d; e++) {
        if (array[e] > array[e + 1]) {
          aux = array[e];
          array[e] = array[e + 1];
          array[e + 1] = aux;
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
  }

  if (opciones == 2) {
    var aux;
    for (var d = 0; d < array.length; d++) {
      for (var e = 0; e < array.length - d; e++) {
        if (array[e] < array[e + 1]) {
          aux = array[e];
          array[e] = array[e + 1];
          array[e + 1] = aux;
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
  }
}

console.log(validar([1, 2, 3])); // array de números => true
console.log(validar(['1', 2, 3])); // array de strings y números => false
console.log(validar([])); // array sin elementos => false
console.log(validar('1')); // es un string y no un array => false
console.log(validar(1)); // es un number y no un array => false
console.log(validar()); // no recibe ningún parámetro => false
```